# Is there any generic Parse() function that will convert a string to any type using parse?

Tags: c#, string, parsing, type-conversion

I want to convert a string to a generic type like `int` or `date` or `long` based on the generic return type.

Basically a function like `Parse<T>(String)` that returns an item of type `T`.

For example if a int was passed the function should do `int.parse` internally.

Answer (score 154, accepted):

[System.Convert.ChangeType](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.convert.changetype.aspx)

As per your example, you could do:

```
int i = (int)Convert.ChangeType("123", typeof(int));
DateTime dt = (DateTime)Convert.ChangeType("2009/12/12", typeof(DateTime));
```

To satisfy your "generic return type" requirement, you could write your own extension method:

```
public static T ChangeType<T>(this object obj)
{
    return (T)Convert.ChangeType(obj, typeof(T));
}
```

This will allow you to do:

```
int i = "123".ChangeType<int>();
```

Comment: cool , but the strange thing its named ChangeType , so i would thought that this function does some kind of cast and not parse

Comment: MSDN says it is simply a wrapper that finds the right conversion method on the source object, requiring that it implements the IConvertible interface.

Comment: If it needs to implement `IConvertable` shouldn't you also constrain the `T`, i.e. `T ChangeType<T>(this object obj) where T : IConvertable`?

Comment: @Liam: No, it's `obj` that must be `IConvertible`, but there's no way to specify that at compile-time.

Comment: if I need something like TryChangeType that returns null or false in fail case? Only by catching exception?

Comment: I am doing exactly this in my code.... The trouble is is won't cast `1` as a boolean. Is there a generic way of handling all value types

Comment: @Liam I know this is an old comment but can't you use, `T ChangeType<T>(this IConvertible obj)` to ensure that obj is an IConvertible?

Answer (score 31):

Well looks like I am too late for answering on this thread. But here is my implementation:

Basically, I have created an Extention method for the Object class. It handles all the types, i.e nullable, classes, and struct.

```
 public static T ConvertTo<T>(this object value)
           {
               T returnValue;

               if (value is T variable)
                   returnValue = variable;
               else
                   try
                   {
                       //Handling Nullable types i.e, int?, double?, bool? .. etc
                       if (Nullable.GetUnderlyingType(typeof(T)) != null)
                       {
                           TypeConverter conv = TypeDescriptor.GetConverter(typeof(T));
                           returnValue = (T) conv.ConvertFrom(value);
                       }
                       else
                       {
                           returnValue = (T) Convert.ChangeType(value, typeof(T));
                       }
                   }
                   catch (Exception)
                   {
                       returnValue = default(T);
                   }

               return returnValue;
           }
```

Comment: IMHO this is the better answer cause it also contains the "nullable"-aspect

Comment: is there a specific reason why you are using `TypeDescriptor` for nullable types and `Convert.ChangeType` for non-nullable ones? This whole `try` block can be reduced only to `TypeConverter` 2 lines of code and it will work for both, nullable and non-nullable.

Answer (score 16):

cleaner version of [Pranay's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/49627291/237917)

```
public static T ConvertTo<T>(this object value)
{
    if (value is T variable) return variable;

    try
    {
        //Handling Nullable types i.e, int?, double?, bool? .. etc
        if (Nullable.GetUnderlyingType(typeof(T)) != null)
        {
            return (T)TypeDescriptor.GetConverter(typeof(T)).ConvertFrom(value);
        }

        return (T)Convert.ChangeType(value, typeof(T));
    }
    catch (Exception)
    {
        return default(T);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 10):

As of C# 11 and .Net 7, this is now possible and supported thanks to static methods on interfaces.

The new [IParsable<TSelf>](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.iparsable-1) provides a static Parse method:

```
abstract static TSelf Parse(string s, IFormatProvider? provider);
```

All the common value types (int, decimal, Guid, etc) implement this interface, but with one exception: `Nullable<T>` doesn't, as obviously the `T` in nullable cannot be assumed to implement `IParsable<T>`. But this shouldn't be an issue in practice (example provided below).

Here's a simple extension method to make use of it:

```
public static T Parse<T>(this string s, IFormatProvider? provider = null) where T : IParsable<T>
{
    return T.Parse(s, provider);
}
```

So, for example, a call of `myString.Parse<int>` will directly call `int.Parse` without boxing, or the need for checking the type at runtime.

Example usage:

```
string s = "5";
int i = s.Parse<int>();
double d = s.Parse<double>();

// Need Nullable<T> support? Just use the null-conditional operator.
string? s2 = null;
decimal? d2 = s2?.Parse<decimal>();
```

Answer (score 9):

`System.Convert.ChangeType` does not convert to any type. Think of the following:

- nullable types
- enums
- Guid etc.

These conversions are possible with [this implementation of ChangeType](https://web.archive.org/web/20180809000121/https://www.siepman.nl/blog/post/2012/03/06/Convert-to-unknown-generic-type-ChangeType-T.aspx).

Answer (score 0):

There are a couple of conventions in the .NET to convert objects of one type to another.

- [Convert.ChangeType](https://learn.microsoft.com/dotnet/api/system.convert.changetype) if the type implements [IConvertible](https://learn.microsoft.com/dotnet/api/system.iconvertible)
- [TypeDescriptor.GetConverter](https://learn.microsoft.com/dotnet/api/system.componentmodel.typedescriptor.getconverter) if the type has a [TypeConverterAttribute](https://learn.microsoft.com/dotnet/api/system.componentmodel.typeconverterattribute)

But these methods are much slower than your typical `T.Parse(string)`, cause boxing and involve lots of allocations each time you want to convert a single value.

For [ValueString](https://github.com/safakgur/value-string), I chose to find a suitable, static parsing method of the type using reflection, build a lambda expression calling it and cache the compiled delegate for future use (See [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/47365478/704144) for an example).

It also fallbacks to the ways I mentioned above if the type doesn't have a suitable parsing method (See the [performance section](https://github.com/safakgur/value-string#internals-and-performance) in the readme).

```
var v = new ValueString("15"); // struct
var i = v.As<int>(); // Calls int.Parse.
```