# is there an enum for all the basic reference types in .net?

Tags: c#, types

well i want an enum i can use in switch function.
i need to get that enum using something like iValue.GetType().somethingidontknow()
so basically this system enum should contain all the basic reference types like int , string , long and so on.
thanks

Comment: int and long aren't reference types.

Comment: `int`, `string`, `long` and so on are C# specific, and probably won't be found outside the compiler classes for C#.  The closest you're likely to get would be `Int32`, `String`, or `Long`.

Comment: What exactly does "and so on" mean? Should it include `decimal`, which has support built into C# but not the CLR, for example? Any reason not to define your own enum?

Comment: well "and so on" means most of basic the primitive types , well i dont want to define my own enum because i dont want to reinvite the wheel

Comment: @Jon Hanna : sorry for the wording but i am asking about the concept itself.

Comment: @Karim: "Most of the basic types" is pretty vague. How can we know whether or not any particular answer would be correct if we don't know what you need?

Comment: @Jon Skeet: well Quartermeister answered System.TypeCode Enum and it contain basically all what i need. and it includes decimal too (althought i wont be needing it).

Comment: well i need to say in the question i need an enum of basic types, that would be clearer i think.

Comment: also i think the error was that i said reference types altought i wanted value types :)

Comment: @Karim: The point is that if you're vague in your requirements, it makes it very hard to answer you. For exmaple, these *aren't* the primitive types in the CLR, which *might* have been what you were after.

Comment: strange that this question got 1 upvote :)
i didnt think its worth any upvotes :) besides its written wrongly :)

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You might want [System.TypeCode](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.typecode.aspx).  You can use [Convert.GetTypeCode](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.convert.gettypecode.aspx) to get the TypeCode for an object or [Type.GetTypeCode](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.type.gettypecode.aspx) to get the TypeCode for a type.  Note that this will be TypeCode.Object for any type that doesn't have its own value in the enumeration.

---

Edit: In case this is related to [your other recent question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3502493/is-there-a-generic-parse-function-that-will-convert-a-string-to-any-type-using), there is an overload of [Convert.ChangeType](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ttf5d382.aspx) that takes a TypeCode, so you can do things like `Convert.ChangeType("123", TypeCode.Int32)`.

Comment: thanks, its a little related to my other question, i am still thinking of implementing my own switch for convertion function Convert<T>(String) so this why i need this enum.