# How to make a generic number parser in C#?

Tags: c#, .net, string, parsing, numbers

To parse a string to an int, one calls `Int32.Parse(string)`, for double, `Double.Parse(string)`, for long, `Int64.Parse(string)`, and so on..

Is it possible to create a method that makes it generic, for example, `ParseString<T>(string)`? where `T` can be `Int32`, `Double`, etc. I notice the number of types don't implement any common interface, and the `Parse` methods don't have any common parent.

Is there any way to achieve this or something similar to this?

Comment: What about something like - If(int.TryParse(...)) else if (double.TryParse ....

Answer (score 14, accepted):

You'd basically have to use reflection to find the relevant static `Parse` method, invoke it, and cast the return value back to `T`. Alternatively, you could use [`Convert.ChangeType`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.convert.changetype.aspx) or get the relevant [`TypeDescriptor`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.componentmodel.typedescriptor.aspx) and associated [`TypeConverter`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.componentmodel.typeconverter.aspx).

A more limited but efficient (and simple, in some ways) approach would be to keep a dictionary from type to parsing delegate - cast the delegate to a `Func<string, T>` and invoke it. That would allow you to use different methods for different types, but you'd need to know the types you needed to convert to up-front.

Whatever you do, you won't be able to specify a generic constraint which would make it safe at compile-time though. Really you need something like my idea of [static interfaces](https://msmvps.com/blogs/jon_skeet/archive/2008/08/29/lessons-learned-from-protocol-buffers-part-4-static-interfaces.aspx) for that kind of thing. EDIT: As mentioned, there's the [`IConvertible`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.iconvertible.aspx) interface, but that doesn't necessarily mean that you'll be able to convert from `string`. Another type *could* implement `IConvertible` without having any way of converting to that type from a string.

Comment: Thanks, those are really good workarounds. Can you explain a bit more for the one using Convert.ChangeType? Opened the links but I still don't understand how it works.

Comment: @Louis: You'd just call `Convert.ChangeType(value, typeof(T))` and then cast the return value to `T`.

Comment: Oh. So what's wrong with using that and wrapping it in a try-catch block?

Comment: @Louis: Nothing necessarily - I'm not sure I'd even use a try/catch block necessarily; it depends on the context.

Answer (score 5):

Actually, the standard number types **do** implement a common interface: [IConvertible](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.iconvertible.aspx). This is the one that `Convert.ChangeType` use.

Unfortunately, there is no `TryParse` equivalent, it will throw exceptions if the string cannot be parsed.

As a side note, it seems this whole "conversion" area has been completely forgotten by the BCL team. There is nothing new there since .NET Framework 1 (except from TryParse methods).

Comment: What's wrong with using that and wrapping it in a try-catch block? Doesn't it function like TryParse?

Comment: @Louis - Sure, but raising exceptions is not recommended in normal execution paths (for performance and other reasons). That's why all the TryParse methods have been added to the Parse methods. But there is no "ITryConvertible" interface :/

Answer (score 3):

This is very hackish, but it works using **[Newtonsoft.Json (Json.NET)](https://github.com/JamesNK/Newtonsoft.Json)**:

```
 JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<double>("24.11");
 // Type == System.Double - Value: 24.11

 JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<int>("29.4");
 // Type == System.Int32 - Value: 29
```

Comment: The benefit with this approach is that you can have not only simple types like bool, int, string, but also more complex custom types.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, the types that can be parsed from a string will most likely have static `Parse` and `TryParse` overloads that you can find via reflection like Jon suggested.

```
private static Func<string, T> GetParser<T>()
{
    // The method we are searching for accepts a single string.
    // You can add other types, like IFormatProvider to target specific overloads.
    var signature = new[] { typeof(string) };

    // Get the method with the specified name and parameters.
    var method = typeof(T).GetMethod("Parse", signature);

    // Initialize the parser delegate.
    return s => (T)method.Invoke(null, new[] { s });
}
```

Performance-wise - `Invoke` method accepts the method parameters as an `object[]` which is an unnecessary allocation and if your parameters include value types, causes boxing. It also returns an `object`, causing the resulting number (assuming it's a value type as well) to be boxed.

To counter that, you can build lambda expressions:

```
private static Func<string, T> GetParser<T>()
{
    // Get the method like we did before.
    var signature = new[] { typeof(string) };
    var method = typeof(T).GetMethod("Parse", signature);

    // Build and compile a lambda expression.
    var param = Expression.Parameter(typeof(string));
    var call = Expression.Call(method, param);
    var lambda = Expression.Lambda<Func<string, T>>(call, param);
    return lambda.Compile();
}
```

Calling the compiled lambda expression is virtually as fast as calling the original parsing method itself, but building and compiling it in the first place is not. This is why, again like Jon suggested, we should cache the resulting delegate.

I use a static, generic class to cache parsers in [ValueString](https://github.com/safakgur/value-string).

```
private static class Parser<T>
{
    public static readonly Func<string, T> Parse = InitParser();

    private static Func<string, T> InitParser()
    {
        // Our initialization logic above.
    }
}
```

After that your parsing method can be written like this:

```
public static T Parse<T>(string s)
{
    return Parser<T>.Parse(s);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I have written some code that uses reflection to find `Parse`/`TryParse` methods on a type and access these from generic functions:

```
private static class ParseDelegateStore<T>
{
    public static ParseDelegate<T> Parse;
    public static TryParseDelegate<T> TryParse;
}

private delegate T ParseDelegate<T>(string s);
private delegate bool TryParseDelegate<T>(string s, out T result);


public static T Parse<T>(string s)
{
    ParseDelegate<T> parse = ParseDelegateStore<T>.Parse;
    if (parse == null)
    {
        parse = (ParseDelegate<T>)Delegate.CreateDelegate(typeof(ParseDelegate<T>), typeof(T), "Parse", true);
        ParseDelegateStore<T>.Parse = parse;
    }
    return parse(s);
}

public static bool TryParse<T>(string s, out T result)
{
    TryParseDelegate<T> tryParse = ParseDelegateStore<T>.TryParse;
    if (tryParse == null)
    {
        tryParse = (TryParseDelegate<T>)Delegate.CreateDelegate(typeof(TryParseDelegate<T>), typeof(T), "TryParse", true);
            ParseDelegateStore<T>.TryParse = tryParse;
    }
    return tryParse(s, out result);
}
```

https://github.com/CodesInChaos/ChaosUtil/blob/master/Chaos.Util/Conversion.cs

But I haven't tested them too much, so they might stiff have some bugs/not work correctly with every type. The error handling is a bit lacking too.

And they have no overloads for culture invariant parsing. So you probably need to add that.