# Generic string parser

Tags: c#, c#-4.0

I need a generic method that can return a value parsed from a string

```
public T GetDefaultValue<T>(){
    // if typeof(T) is Double it should try to parse some string (supposedly which's been read from DB), 
    // and return Double value, or if typeof(T) is Int, then it should parse the string 
    //into Int, and finally if typeof(T) is a string, then no parsing is needed.
}
```

**UPD...** Why can't I check if T is some certain type and use Parse method accordingly?

Comment: Please read this: http://tinyurl.com/so-hints

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6160329/is-it-possible-to-make-a-generic-number-parser-in-c Is a similar question. But I'm not sure if it counts as exact duplicate.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`Convert.ChangeType` could be used to make your conversions.

```
public T Parse<T>(string input)
{
     return (T)Convert.ChangeType(input, typeof(T));
}

int x = Parse<int>("1");
double y = Parse<double>("1.0");
string z = Parse<string>("hey");
```

Notice that to even make this work, you are specifying your types? What's the savings over using `int.Parse` (or `TryParse`), `double.Parse`, etc.?

**And since you mention your inputs are likely coming from a database**, and still knowing that to even use the above method you have to specify the type parameter already, I would encourage you to (a) know and trust your types and (b) use existing functionality to obtain values from data sources. No need to convert something to a string and then convert it back to whatever data type you wish it to be.

```
int x = myDataRow.Field<int>("Column1"); // or
int x = (int)myDataRow["Column1"];
```

This also supports if the numeric values could be nullable in the database.

```
int? x = myDataRow.Field<int?>("Column1"); // or
int x = myDataRow.Field<int?>("Column1").GetValueOrDefault(); // normalize nulls to 0
```

Answer (score 1):

What is the point of using generics for this? You lose all benefits of generics by checking for actual types.

Just have three overloads, one for `int`, one for `double` and (the probably unneeded) `string`.

Comment: if I'm remembering right methods' signatures cannot be different only in return types

Comment: @Agzam - You recall correctly. But if you pass an `int` versus a `double` versus a `string`, they are different _parameter_ types.

Answer (score 1):

You can do something like this without generics. Why use a sword when all you need is a needle

```
class Test
    {
        public string ReadFromDb()
        {
            //Do your db work here
            return "";
        }

        public bool GetDefaultValue(ref int t1)
        {
            t1 = Int32.Parse(ReadFromDb());
            return true;
        }

        public bool GetDefaultValue(ref double t1)
        {
            t1 = Double.Parse( ReadFromDb() );
            return true;
        }

        public bool GetDefaultValue(ref string t1)
        {
            t1 = ReadFromDb();
            return true;
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

I would just make string extensions like

```
public static int xToInt(this string source, int alternate = 0)
{
   int result;
   return (int.TryParse(source, out result) ? result : alternate);
}
```

And then just create one for Double and you could then use it by doing

```
int someNumber  = "123456".xToInt();
int someNumber2 = "omg!".xToInt(333);
```

Answer (score 1):

I wrote generic methods that use reflection to search an appropriate `Parse` method and call it. But they won't work if you want to transform `string` to `string` since `string` doesn't have a `Parse` method. So you'll need to add a special case for `string`.

I don't understand why your function is called `GetDefaultValue` either. Why not `Parse`, `TryParse`, `ConvertFromString` or something like that? When seeing a function called  `GetDefaultValue`, I don't think of a parsing function.

Check this old question:
[Is it possible to make a generic number parser in C#?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6160329/is-it-possible-to-make-a-generic-number-parser-in-c) which has several relevant answers.

---

And my old answer from there:

I have written some code that uses reflection to find `Parse`/`TryParse` methods on a type and access these from generic functions:

```
private static class ParseDelegateStore<T>
{
    public static ParseDelegate<T> Parse;
    public static TryParseDelegate<T> TryParse;
}

private delegate T ParseDelegate<T>(string s);
private delegate bool TryParseDelegate<T>(string s, out T result);


public static T Parse<T>(string s)
{
    ParseDelegate<T> parse = ParseDelegateStore<T>.Parse;
    if (parse == null)
    {
        parse = (ParseDelegate<T>)Delegate.CreateDelegate(typeof(ParseDelegate<T>), typeof(T), "Parse", true);
        ParseDelegateStore<T>.Parse = parse;
    }
    return parse(s);
}

public static bool TryParse<T>(string s, out T result)
{
    TryParseDelegate<T> tryParse = ParseDelegateStore<T>.TryParse;
    if (tryParse == null)
    {
        tryParse = (TryParseDelegate<T>)Delegate.CreateDelegate(typeof(TryParseDelegate<T>), typeof(T), "TryParse", true);
            ParseDelegateStore<T>.TryParse = tryParse;
    }
    return tryParse(s, out result);
}
```

https://github.com/CodesInChaos/ChaosUtil/blob/master/Chaos.Util/Conversion.cs

But I haven't tested them too much, so they might stiff have some bugs/not work correctly with every type. The error handling is a bit lacking too.

And they have no overloads for culture invariant parsing. So you probably need to add that.