# Generic parsable class for nullables

Tags: c#, class, parsing

I'm trying to code a generic struct to parse nullable types.

I have several problems:

1. I can't inherit `Nullable<T>` cause it's a struct:

   ```
   public struct NullableParsable<T> : Nullable<T> where T : struct { }
   ```

> Type T in interface list is not an interface

So I try with:

```
    public struct NullableParsable<T> where T : struct
    {
        public static T? Parse(string s)
        {
            T? result = null;
            string tName = typeof(T).Name;
            switch(tName)
            {
                case "Int32": result = string.IsNullOrEmpty(s) ? null : (int?)int.Parse(s); break;
                case "Decimal": result = string.IsNullOrEmpty(s) ? null : (decimal?)decimal.Parse(s); break;
                default: throw new NotImplementedException("unmanaged type: "+ tName);
            }

            return result;
        }
    }
```

2. I can't cast `int` to `T` or `int?` to `T?`.
3. I would like a simple way to switch among struct types (maybe an enum), for the moment I switch among type names `typeof(T).Name`. Or maybe a reflection mecanism to invoke `Parse`...

See complete code in this fiddle: https://dotnetfiddle.net/x6kHzx

Any idea of how to properly implement this functionality?

Comment: How can you write a meaningful generic *implementation* here? Parsing `int`s and parsing `DateTime`s looks quite different, not to mention custom structs.

Comment: @Damien_The_Unbeliever I just have to call the corresponding type's `Parse` function

Answer (score -1, accepted):

In fact, I just have to declare my result as a `dynamic` then I can assign it a `Nullable` and return it as a `T?`:

```
public static T? Parse(string s)
{
    dynamic result = null;
    int intValue;
    result = int.TryParse(s, out intValue) ? (int?)intValue : null;
    return result;
}
```

---

And with relfection, I can invoke Parse:

```
public static T? Parse(string s)
{
    dynamic result = null;
    Type type = typeof(T);
    string tName = type.Name;
    MethodInfo methodInfo = type.GetMethod("Parse", new[] { typeof(string) });
    result = methodInfo.Invoke(null, new[] { s });
    return result;
}
```

---

Better, I can invoke TryParse to avoid try/catch:

```
public static T? Parse(string s)
{
    Type type = typeof(T);
    string tName = type.Name;
    MethodInfo methodInfo = type.GetMethod("TryParse", new[] { typeof(string), type.MakeByRefType() });
    object[] args = new object[] { s, null };
    bool parsed = (bool)methodInfo.Invoke(null, args);
    dynamic result = parsed ? args[1] : null;
    return result;
}
```

**Updated [fiddle](https://dotnetfiddle.net/x6kHzx)**

Related posts:
[How to call TryParse dynamically?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11481853/how-to-call-tryparse-dynamically),
[Generic TryParse](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2961656/generic-tryparse),

Comment: `dynamic` shouldn't be necessary here, and can be expressed by `T`/`T?`.

Comment: @Caramiriel `dynamic` needed because I can't cast an object to `T`/`T?`.

Answer (score 1):

Since you'll not be able to deal with all `struct`s (outside of hardcoded list, no `Parse` locatable by reflection), I'd instead recommend some extension methods on `string`, for *those types you know how to support*. E.g.

```
public static class ParseExtensions {
    public static int? ParseInt(this string input)
    {
        if(Int32.TryParse(input,out var result)
        {
           return result;
        }
        return null;
    }

    public static DateTime? ParseDateTime(this string input)
    {
        if(DateTime.TryParse(input, out var result)
        {
            return result;
        }
        return null;
    }
}
```

You get no benefits from generics here anyway, because all of the `Parse`/`TryParse` methods are separate methods that just happen to share a name. They don't have a shared inheritance/interface ancestor.

Comment: This is very much like something I use myself - only the names are different - and the DateTime have a few useful overloads (to handle different formats and stuff like that). +1.

Comment: and why not just directly use TryParse when you can also use `out var`

Comment: It works but it's not elegant, I want something generic

Comment: @sinsedrix - there is **no** point in writing a generic here. As I tried to indicate, all you "add" with a generic here is code that's going to fail at runtime due to the fact that you cannot actually write a generic implementation and you'll be switching on known types and/or relying on reflection. You're taking compile time type safety and turning it into a runtime error.

Comment: I prefer switching on class names than writing N methods

Comment: @sinsedrix - we'll have practically the same number of *lines of code*, and my code doesn't lie about its abilities, maintaining type safety.

Answer (score 1):

Apart from advice already given, what you can do is use a dictionary instead of a switch statement to make it a bit more dynamic. This doesn't change that only specified types can be parsed.

For example, you can create a class that knows how to parse these types:

```
public class NullableParsable
{
    private static readonly Dictionary<string, Func<string, object>> _parsers =
        new Dictionary<string, Func<string, object>>();

    public static void Register<T>(Func<string, T?> parser)
        where T : struct
    {
        var key = typeof(T).FullName;
        _parsers.Add(key, x => parser(x));
    }

    public static T? Parse<T>(string value)
        where T : struct
    {
        var key = typeof(T).FullName;
        if (_parsers.TryGetValue(key, out var parser))
        {
            if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(value))
            {
                return null;
            }

            return (T?) parser(value);
        }

        throw new NotSupportedException("Not sure how to map this type");
    }
}
```

And after that, specify how to parse specific types:

```
NullableParsable.Register<int>(s => int.Parse(s));
NullableParsable.Register<decimal>(s => decimal.Parse(s));
NullableParsable.Register<Guid>(s => Guid.Parse(s));
```

Example usage:

```
int? result1 = NullableParsable.Parse<int>("123");
decimal? result2 = NullableParsable.Parse<decimal>("123");
Guid? result3 = NullableParsable.Parse<Guid>(Guid.NewGuid().ToString("D"));
```