# How do I write a generic Convert function?

Tags: c#, c#-4.0

I am trying to write a generic convert function but I don't know how do I do that. This is my skeleton:

```
public static T ConvertByGenerics<T>(string value)
        {
            //what do I write here?
            return default(T);
        }
```

Can anybody help me out? What do I write within the function to dynamically convert string into type T?

Comment: You want _any_ type to be parseable from a string?

Comment: yeah, sort of. If I say ConvertByGenerics<int>("10"), it should give me 10 in integer.

Comment: you can see following post

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6884653/how-to-make-a-generic-type-cast-function

Comment: `Convert.toInt()` / Double / String etc etc.

Comment: possible duplicate of [is there a generic Parse() function that will convert a string to any type using parse?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3502493/is-there-a-generic-parse-function-that-will-convert-a-string-to-any-type-using)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try something like:

```
public T ConvertByGenerics<T>(string value, T defaultValue)
{
   if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(value))
   {
      return (T)Convert.ChangeType(value, typeof(T));
   }

   return defaultValue;
}
```

Comment: Excellent!! just need to remove attribute. I don't know what is that for!

Comment: This will fail with invalid cast on most types.

Comment: @Oded: This answer is what I want!!!! I want simple conversions only. Don't want to create a complex object type like Person/Employee out a string. I am not sure who downvoted this answer.

Comment: @TomKaufmann - You didn't specify that in your question. [Stack Overflow is not a Mind Reader](http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/128551/140505).

Comment: This works for all types which implement `IConvertible` interface.

Comment: @MarekDzikiewicz - Most types don't.

Comment: @Oded: I think Oded simply doesn't want to understand the fact that this answer is what the OP (me) wanted. He somehow wants to negatively downvote the correct answer and shout in the forum aimlessly.

Comment: @TomKaufmann - I understand this is what you wanted. I am also saying your question was incomplete and inaccurate in detailing your requirements. It still is. I answered to what you posted - that it doesn't answer your requirements is more a reflection on the quality of the question than anything.

Comment: This generic method adds little value, doesn't it? If you're only interested in basic types, then why not just use Convert.ChangeType directly?

Answer (score 1):

There are some more things you might try, but they involve dynamic methods.
There is not enough exception handling in the snippet, and can certainly be optimized somewhat.

```
public static T ConvertByGenerics<T>(string input) {

    // be mindful of boxing 
    if (input is T) {
        return (T)(object)input;
    }

    if (input == null) {
        // throw arugment exception 
    }

    // can check for int, long ......
    if (typeof(T).IsEnum) {
        return (T)System.Enum.Parse(typeof(T), input, true);
    }

    if (typeof(T).IsAssignableFrom(typeof(string))) {
        return (T)(object)input;
    }

    try {
        return (T)Convert.ChangeType(input, typeof(T));
    }
    catch { //do nothing
    }

    // might want to cache some converters
    System.ComponentModel.TypeConverter converter = System.ComponentModel.TypeDescriptor.GetConverter(typeof(T));
    if (converter.CanConvertFrom(typeof(string))) {
        return (T)converter.ConvertFrom(input);
    }
    else {
        // better though to throw an exception here 
        return default(T);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

What you want is not possible.

In order to support any conceivable type, you need to know how it will be represented as a string - some of the built in value types have `Parse` methods that "understand" certain formats of strings and can parse them into the type, but there is absolutely no way to generically do this for *every conceivable type*.

You need to write code to convert from a string to every type - this is not feasible for every type in existence.

Comment: @TomKaufmann - Try it. Good luck. It will not work on _most_ types.

Comment: It works atleast for my situation. I just need simple conversions. Obviously I can't pass a type Person/Employee and expect a Person/Employee object out of a string :p.

Comment: @TomKaufmann - Why didn't you say _simple_ conversions? And between _what types_? Generic is generic - I have assumed `Person` or `Order` may be a valid conversion...

Comment: Never mind if you misunderstood my question. devdigital already has the right answer. Obviously you should understand that it is not possible. You can't automagically get those types from string. Can you? The thing that was obvious should not be mentioned.

Comment: @TomKaufmann - If I misunderstood it is because the question was _incomplete_. You left some crucial details off it.

Comment: Crucial? You think it was crucial? How did devdigital get what I wanted to say? and in my comment also I wrote what I want 'ConvertByGenerics<int>("10")'? Did you managed to read that? It was pretty obvious I don't want to create complex type from a string.

Comment: @TomKaufmann - **In your comment**. Not in the body of the **question**. It was only _clear_ **AFTER** you commented.

Comment: If you say you want a generic conversion to get anything out as T it is going to be assumed that you want to put anything in to get T. It Wasn't obvious that you only wanted basic conversions, so Oded provided information proving why you couldn't do it. we can only assume you know the things you tell us

Comment: @Oded: You posted this answer after I posted my comment!!

Comment: @TomKaufmann - I took the comment to be **one example** only. It can still be seen as one possible example.

Comment: @Oded: In your 1st comment you mentioned ". It was only clear AFTER you commented." and now you say I took only to be one example? Why don't you accept that devdigital's answer is correct?

Comment: @TomKaufmann - As for the answer by devdigital - I can't control the assumptions he made. That he was right in his assumption is also something I can't control. He might not have been.

Comment: @Anthony - That one example was clear, but it was not clear it was the way the OP wanted to convert. Do you think it was clear?

Comment: Anthony, because technically it isnt, devs solution will work only for a few cases, Oded explains why it will only work for a few cases. The question asked how to turn into Type T, never specifying what type t could be, so Oded took it to mean ANY TYPE and you cant convert it into any type, oded explains why. Devs answer is correct given the narrow scope of what is wanted. oded is correct because he explains why its only for a narrow scope, both answers are correct yet oded is being punished for providing the knowledge behind why this answer is limited

Comment: @Oded: You still haven't answered "In your 1st comment you mentioned ". It was only clear AFTER you commented." and now you say I took only to be one example?"

Comment: @RhysW: Oded explained a thing that was not at all necessary to be explained. Do you think a person needs to explained if you stop breathing you will die?

Comment: @Anthony - Just answer this - in your eyes, is the question clear enough, even with that comment? Do you think, in view of the question and that one comment that my answer is valid/reasonable or not? If not, please explain why.

Comment: @TomKaufmann - I am not a mind reader. I don't know what you do and do not know. I can only go on **what you posted**.

Comment: if someone asks what happens if i stop breathing then yes that will be the answer, how are we meant to know you meant a narrow scope of what t might be? you dont SAY it will be int or double or whatever you just say type T, we dont know your background, we dont know the extent of your knowledge. we only have the info in the question to go on,

Comment: @Oded: You are right. The question isn't correct. By type T you took the literal meaning of converting string to anything. But let's now stop this conversation here itself. I will appreciate if the OP also doesn't stretch this more :)