# Get an instance of a generic class using Reflection

Tags: c#, generics, reflection, types, casting

I've a container with a set of `Property`.

```
public class Property<T> : INotifyPropertyChanged
{
    private T _value;

    public Property(string name)
    {
        Name = name;
    }

    public Property(string name, T value)
        : this(name)
    {
        _value = value;
    }

    public string Name { get; }

    public T Value
    {
        get
        {
            return _value;
        }
        set
        {
            if(_value == null || !_value.Equals(value))
            {
                _value = value;

                if (PropertyChanged != null)
                {
                    PropertyChanged(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(Name));
                }
            }
        }
    }

    public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;
}
```

As you can see, the Property is made `Generic` because the type can be different.
The problem is that the properties are configurable by this piece of xml:

```
<InputProperties> 
   <Property Type="System.UInt64" Name="Id"/>    
   <Property Type="System.DateTime" Name="Timestamp"/>   
   <Property Type="System.Byte" Name="State"/>    
</InputProperties>
```

So my steps should be:

1.

Initializes the container, which contains a `List<Property<dynamic>>` (don't like dynamic but it's the only way to solve compiling error)

2.

Parse the xml and create the generic type via reflection

```
foreach(XElement xProperty in allconfiguredInputParameters)
{
   string xPropertyType = xProperty.Attribute("Type") != null ? xProperty.Attribute("Type").Value : String.Empty;
   string xPropertyName = xProperty.Attribute("Name") != null ? xProperty.Attribute("Name").Value : String.Empty;

   if (!String.IsNullOrEmpty(xPropertyType) && !String.IsNullOrEmpty(xPropertyName))
   {
      Type genericProperty = typeof(Property<>);
      Type constructedGenericProperty = genericProperty.MakeGenericType(new Type[] { GetTypeByFullname(xPropertyType) });

      var property = constructedGenericProperty.GetConstructor(new Type[] { typeof(String) }).Invoke(new object[] { xPropertyName });          
    }
 }
```

The property as object contains the data I want but I can't cast it to Property. What I would like to do is:

```
myContainer.InputParamers.Add((Parameter<T>)property));
```

but naturally it doesn't work. Could you give me some tips? Thank you.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Is there any generic Parse() function that will convert a string to any type using parse?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3502493/is-there-any-generic-parse-function-that-will-convert-a-string-to-any-type-usi)

Comment: You can't force a `Something<T>` into a `Something<dynamic>` it just transforms the compile error into a runtime error. You have to choose a generic-less ancestor to store them in the same collection like: `INotifyPropertyChanged`. Why do you need an xml descriptor for the properties? Wouldn't be easier to have a class that describes these properties with strict type parameters? If you don't have the generic type information (with the xml solution you wouldn't have it at all) you have to use direct cast everytime you want to access those properties.

Comment: It might help to know how you're planning on using the container.